# is it mandatory to migrate java 8 to java 11/17 on google cloud

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, gwt

Currently our project is on java 8 and we can deploy on google cloud using google cloud tools in eclipse.

we dont want to upgrade to java 11/17 it will any impact on our application ?

if we dont migrate our application then our application will run on java 8 on google cloud lifetime ?

and now currently using java 8 and eclipse google cloud tools we are deploying on google cloud it will support for lifetime ?

please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/supported-java-versions):

> Java 8 will continue to be supported by Cloud Client Libraries for Java until at least September 2026.

Comment: Thank you @Jorn for response i want to know one more thing currently we are deploying our application using google cloud tools from eclipse on google cloud is there any impact on this ?

Comment: I don't see why there would be. But check the documentation for that plugin (I guess).